# What is the connection between the two definitions of homology in 1.1 of Rotman's An Introduction to Homological Algebra?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

In 1.1 of Rotman's *An Introduction to Homological Algebra*, the author traces back to the origin of homology theory.

Rotman begins with discussion about line integrals. For a open set $X$ in the plane, he define $\beta$ and $\beta'$ to be equivalent if for all closed $1$-form $\omega$, $\int_{\beta}\omega = \int_{\beta'}\omega$, where $\beta$ and $\beta'$ are both linear combinations of paths in $X$. He calls the equivalent classes 'homology class' (which is the first definition).

Then the author terminates discussing line integrals. He turns to topics including 'the group $Z_n(X)$ of all simplicial $n$-cycles' and 'the group $B_n(X)$ of all simplicial $n$-boundaries' (where $X$ is assumed to be a finite simplicial complex), and eventually reaches another definition, "the $n$th simplicial homology group of $X$ is $H_n(X) = Z_n(X)/B_n(X)$" (the second difinition).

I have the following questions:

1. What's the connection between these two definitions of homology? Are they equivalent under certain circumstances?
2. How does the former definition lead to the latter one? Rotman does not leave many clues but merely asserts that "homology can be defined without using integration of function pairs". I can see both definitions are somewhat related to holes in the space, but nothing more.

Comment: The answer is: read about homology of spaces in an algebraic topology book.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry, Rotman just wants to give examples of the use of the term "homology" in mathematics. It should be a motivational introduction, but I am afraid that it is not really a felicitous beginning. Many readers will probably be confused about Rotman's message in chapter 1.1.

There is no direct transition from the concept of the *homology class of a formal sum of paths in open subsets of the plane* (in the context of line integrals in analysis) to the concept of the *simplicial homology groups of a simplicial complex*. However, he also gives an account on the *singular homology groups of a topological space*, and here you see that free abelian group generated by the sets of all paths in a space $X$ (which is the abelian group of all formal sums of such paths) is nothing else than the abelian group of singular $1$-chains in $X$. This leaves open what homology classes occurring in the context of line integrals have to do with the elements  of the first singular homology group (which are also called homology classes, though Rotman does not mention it). Anyway, it is at least a starting point to see a connection.

There is indeed a connection between these three concepts, but one can only see it from a higher point of view requiring considerable experience in algebraic topology. There are certainly readers who have this knowledge. In
"How to Read This Book" Rotman writes

> Homological Algebra developed from Algebraic Topology,
> and it is best understood if one knows its origins, which are described in Sections 1.1 and 1.3.

For other readers chapter 1 is perhaps more confusing than enlightening. And, by the way, Rotman does not take up the concepts of chapter 1.1 later in his book; this indicates to me that he should better have omitted this chapter.